# How to set the cookie in custom library in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, cookies, codeigniter-3

Hello I am trying to set the cookie in my custom library `CI_Snippetfunctions` something like this

```
class CI_Snippetfunctions
{

public function add_count($slug)
{



  $check_visitor = $this->input->cookie(urldecode($slug), FALSE);

   $ip = $this->input->ip_address();

   if ($check_visitor == false) {
    $cookie = array(
        "name"   => urldecode($slug),
        "value"  => "$ip",
        "expire" =>  time() + 7200,
        "secure" => false
    );

    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
    $this->Constant_model->update_counter(urldecode($slug));
    }
   }
  }
```

But I am getting the following error

[image]

Comment: did you loaded cookie helper i.e, $this->load->helper('cookie');?

Comment: I tried this $this->load->helper('cookie'); but still getting the error as this already a library

Comment: $this is not allowed here!! after inserting  $this->load->helper('cookie');  am getting error - Message: Undefined property: CI_Snippetfunctions::$load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, i m not sure about but still

```
public function add_count($slug)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();//CI super object
    $check_visitor = $CI->input->cookie(urldecode($slug), FALSE);

    $ip = $CI->input->ip_address();

    if ($check_visitor == false) {
        $cookie = array(
            "name"   => urldecode($slug),
            "value"  => "$ip",
            "expire" =>  time() + 7200,
            "secure" => false
        );

        $CI->input->set_cookie($cookie);
        $CI->Constant_model->update_counter(urldecode($slug));
    }
}
```

> To access CodeIgniter’s native resources within your library use the get_instance() method. This method returns the CodeIgniter super object.
>
> Normally from within your controller methods you will call any of the available CodeIgniter methods using the $this construct
>
> $this, however, only works directly within your controllers, your models, or your views. If you would like to use CodeIgniter’s classes from within your own custom classes you can do so as follows: